# Symfony2: Can bundle routes be namespaced?

Tags: symfony, routes, namespaces, twig

I have a MagazineBundle which in one of its Twig templates has `path('portfolio')`, the root of a different bundle that has been prefixed.

```
# app/config/routing.yml

LameMagazineBundle:
    resource: "@LameMagazineBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

LamePortfolioBundle:
    resource: "@LamePortfolioBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /portfolio
```

and

```
# src/Lame/PortfolioBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

portfolio:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: LamePortfolioBundle:Default:index }
```

But if I add a third bundle, possibly one I've downloaded and installed, and that bundle also happened to also have a route named 'portfolio', would I have to renamed the routes or is there a way to namespace them?

An experiment I tried with two matching route names results in the last declared one overriding the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not built into the routing system. You would have to manually prefix your route names with the bundle or some other namespace.

The `FOSRestBundle` has route prefixing functionality but I'm not sure how coupled it is or if it's something that could be easily used without all the bundles other features.

http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/6-automatic-route-generation_multiple-restful-controllers.html#naming-collisions

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the link. I'll do some experimentation to see if I can prefix it, and report back, at which point I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: Now that I'm back to Symfony2 development, I had another look at this. Seems like the solution would be in `FOSRestBundle/Routing/RestRouteCollection.php` if I needed some sort of automatic prefixing functionality.